# 2 ionic not creating the main.css and main.js

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a very strange problem on my computer with Windows 10, the ionic serves not compile the files and the error below, more on another computer the same application works and compiles without error, can someone help me?

```
ionic serve

Running 'serve:before' npm script before serve

> TraduzindoSonhos@ watch C:\Users\Breno\Dropbox\Apps\TraduzindoSonhos\TraduzindoSonhos
> ionic-app-scripts watch

[09:15:23]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.36
[09:15:23]  watch started ...
[09:15:23]  build dev started ...
[09:15:23]  clean started ...
[09:15:23]  clean finished in 15 ms
[09:15:23]  copy started ...
[09:15:24]  transpile started ...
[09:15:24]  lint started ...
[09:15:28]  tslint: ...reno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/services/bmbraga.http.ts,
            line: 4
            Unused import: 'Response'

       L3:  import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
       L4:  import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
       L5:  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

[09:15:28]  tslint: ...reno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/services/bmbraga.http.ts,
            line: 4
            Unused import: 'Headers'

       L3:  import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
       L4:  import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
       L5:  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

[09:15:28]  tslint: ...reno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/services/bmbraga.http.ts,
            line: 4
            Unused import: 'RequestOptions'

       L3:  import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
       L4:  import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
       L5:  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

[09:15:28]  tslint: ...reno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/services/bmbraga.http.ts,
            line: 5
            Unused import: 'Observable'

       L4:  import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
       L5:  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

[09:15:28]  tslint: ...ox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/item-details/item-details.ts,
            line: 88
            Unused variable: 'alert'

      L87:  console.log("login error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      L88:  try {
      L89:      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

[09:15:28]  tslint: ...sers/Breno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/home/home.ts,
            line: 2
            Unused import: 'NavParams'

       L1:  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
       L2:  import { NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
       L3:  import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

[09:15:28]  tslint: ...sers/Breno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/home/home.ts,
            line: 99
            Unused variable: 'alert'

      L98:  try {
      L99:      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
     L100:              title: 'Server error',

[09:15:28]  tslint: .../Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/letter-result/letter-result.ts,
            line: 98
            Unused variable: 'alert'

      L97:  try {
      L98:      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      L99:              title: 'Server error',

[09:15:28]  tslint: .../Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/search-result/search-result.ts,
            line: 85
            Unused variable: 'alert'

      L84:  try {
      L85:      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      L86:              title: 'Server error',

[09:15:28]  lint finished in 4.17 s
[09:15:30]  typescript: ...rs/Breno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/app/app.component.ts,
            line: 37
            Property 'analytics' does not exist on type 'Window'.

      L36:  try {
[09:15:30]  typescript: ...sers/Breno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/home/home.ts,       L37:
        window.            line: 27 a
nal[09:15:30]  typescript: ...sers/Breno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/home/home.ts, y
t            line: 34
i[09:15:30]  typescript: ...sers/Breno/Dropbox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/home/home.ts, c
            line: 68 s
.startTrackerWithId("UA-960473-35");
[09:15:30]  typescript: ...ox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/item-details/item-details.ts,       L38:  }
catch            line: 29  (e) {


            Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

[09:15:30]  typescript: ...ox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/item-details/item-details.ts,       L26:
this.block2Items = [];
            line: 36       L27:
thi[09:15:30]  typescript: ...ox/Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/item-details/item-details.ts, s
.            line: 65 l
oadHomeItems([09:15:30]  typescript: .../Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/letter-result/letter-result.ts,
);
            line: 31       L28:
this.trackEvent();

            Property 'analytics' does not exist on type 'Window'.

[09:15:30]  typescript: .../Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/letter-result/letter-result.ts,       L33:
try            line: 38  {

      L34:      window.anal[09:15:30]  typescript: .../Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/letter-result/letter-result.ts,
y            line: 72 t
ics.trackEvent("Home");
      L35:  } catch (e) {

            Cannot find name 'Response'.

      L68:  dataSuccess(res: Response) {
      L69:      this.loader.dismiss();

            Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

[09:15:30]  typescript: .../Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/search-result/search-result.ts,
      L28:              line: 26 this.itemDetails = null;

      L29:  [09:15:30]  typescript: .../Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/search-result/search-result.ts, t
h            line: 33 i
[09:15:30]  typescript: .../Apps/TraduzindoSonhos/TraduzindoSonhos/src/pages/search-result/search-result.ts, s
.            line: 67 l
oadHomeItems();
      L30:  this.trackEvent();

            Property 'analytics' does not exist on type 'Window'.

      L35:  [09:15:30]  transpile failed
try {
      L36:      window.analytics.trackEvent("Details");
      L37:  } catch (e) {

            Cannot find name 'Response'.

      L65:  dataSuccess(res: Response) {
      L66:      this.loader.dismiss();

            Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

      L30:  this.letter = this.letter.toUpperCase();
      L31:  this.loadHomeItems();
      L32:  this.trackEvent();

            Property 'analytics' does not exist on type 'Window'.

      L37:  try {
      L38:      window.analytics.trackEvent("LSearch", "Letter", this.letter);
      L39:  } catch (e) {

            Cannot find name 'Response'.

      L72:  dataSuccess(res: Response) {
      L73:      this.loadingItems = false;

            Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

      L25:  this.letter = navParams.get('search');
      L26:  this.loadHomeItems();
      L27:  this.trackEvent();

            Property 'analytics' does not exist on type 'Window'.

      L32:  try {
      L33:      window.analytics.trackEvent("LSearch", "Letter", this.letter);
      L34:  } catch (e) {

            Cannot find name 'Response'.

      L67:  dataSuccess(res: Response) {
      L68:      this.loader.dismiss();

[09:15:30]  copy finished in 6.71 s
[09:15:30]  watch ready in 6.79 s
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching: www/**/*, !www/lib/**/*, !www/**/*.map
√ Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

ionic $ q
```

---

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 1.2.2
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.36
OS:
Node Version: v6.9.0

Comment: did you run `npm install` in your project's root directory before running `ionic serve`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are missing the `cordova-plugin-google-analytics` plugin. Run 
`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics` to add it.